# ¿Como excluir un elemento de un ComboBox en C#?

Tags: c#

Me podrian ayudar tengo un grid en el que cargo un control ComboBox el cual esta bindeado a una tabla, el problema es que necesito excluir del ComboBox el elemento actual del grid y mostrar todos los demas.

Intente lo siguiente si funciona pero la tabla me la convierte a una lista de ROWS que cuando se la asigno al DataSource del ComboBox me muestra todas las propiedades del ROW.

Alguien me podria dar una idea? El asunto es muy dinamico ya que se carga un combobox en una columna dl grid y se excluye el elemento en que esta parado del grid.

```
src.DataSource = _datosMesas.AsEnumerable().Where(item => item["Mesa"].ToString() != CurrentMesaValue).ToList();
```

Comment: La consulta que haces te devuelve una `List<DataRow>` entiendo. Intenta añadir despues `.CopyToDataTable()`

Comment: Excelente hice eso para tener de nuevo una tabla y no el list de rows
`foreach (DataRow row in rowArray)
     tablapruebas = rowArray.CopyToDataTable();`